# How to open NERDTree quickly?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-nerdtree

I have read the NERDTree help and found that to close NERDTree, we could type :q.

How can I open NERDTree the shortest way?

I am now typing `:NERDTree`  to open NERDTree, but I think it is too slow for me.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl n</kbd>, but it did not work.

What is the quickest way to open NERDTree in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a mapping:

```
:nnoremap <C-n> <Cmd>NERDTree<CR>
```

Then you could open NERDTree using <kbd>Ctrl n</kbd>.